# Uploading all folder content including subfolders using Spring MVC

Tags: spring, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

My problem is I want to select a folder using a web page and upload all the content of the folder to S3 using Spring.

I have tried the Spring MVC multipartresolver to upload files and it works fine. I have used JetS3t as well to upload folders and files to S3. But how can I select a folder using my web app and tell it to upload all files and subfolders to S3. 
I am using Spring MVC 3.

Answer (score 0):

Not using a "normal" HTML form-based file upload. And this is nothing to do with Spring or amazon, it's just a limitation in HTML. It's been [suggested](http://lists.whatwg.org/pipermail/whatwg-whatwg.org/2009-December/024455.html) in the WHAT working group that this functionality be added, but that's a while ago and I don't think anything ever came of it.

The closes you have is the "[multiple](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_input_multiple.asp)" file selector ("`<input type="file" multiple>`") selector that allows you to select multiple files. Together with the new FileReader API in HTML5 ([example](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/)), this gets you somewhat closer to what you want. Unfortunately, "multiple" is not supported in IE.

For true directory-select and upload, you'll have to look to Java Applets or similar technologies. To be allowed to interact with the file system, an applet would have to be properly signed.